# Grouped Product getAssociatedProducts() is not working in attributes tab template

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-view, grouped-products, product-tab

In the main view template for my grouped products, grouped.phtml, I have had no problems fetching the associated products and displaying some attributes in a loop.

I have done the same thing in a custom version of the attributes.phtml sub-template used to display attributes, and there, the code returns NULL.

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="page-product-grouped"/>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
        <block class="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped" name="product.info.grouped" before="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_GroupedProduct::product/view/type/grouped.phtml"/>
        <container name="product.info.grouped.extra" after="product.info.grouped" before="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data_extra" label="Product Extra Info"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    (...)
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_GroupedProduct::product/view/type/grouped/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">27</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>      
    </referenceBlock>              
</body>
```

I am assuming that the reason is because the second block is of `class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes"` but obviously if I change it to `Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped` then the attribute functionality disappears so I am not better off.

There has to be a way to "cross load" the Grouped functionality into the Attributes block (or vice versa) OR I must use something other than `$block` for the grouped loading code:

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts();
```

but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understood the question is.

> I need the associated products in a template in which I have access to
>   the product. How do I do that?

From the product object you can retrieve the type instance. And from the type instance you can retrieve the associated products.

```
$associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($product);
```

If your product is grouped, getTypeInstance() will return a `Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped` instance which implements **getAssociatedProducts** it also implements **getAssociatedProductsCollection** if you want to add some extra filters.

I hope this answers your question. If I did not get the question right, please put me on the right track.

Comment: Thanks - that certainly "loaded up" the grouped context as I needed. 
Silly question perhaps but if I have already loaded the associated products for this very product in another subtemplate, is this redoing the whole querying and building the whole information again? In a way the groupedproduct codebase should extend attributes too so there is no such need.

Comment: It's a good question. I'm not really sure. You will have to investigate if the same collection is used in both places. There are big chances that the same collection(same instance, not type) is used in both places. A run with the debugger could answer the q.